# How to change the UI colors in Visual Studio, without changing the Font&Text colors in the text editor?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Can I change only the UI (the menus and toolbars and all) colors without changing the text editor colors?
Or are there themes that only change the IDE colors but not the text editor colors?

Answer (score 0):

[Visual Studio Color Theme Designer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-madsk.ColorThemeDesigner) extension allows you to separately customize colors used for menus, toolbars, tabs, titlebars, the text editor, and other environment colors.